# java.lang.IllegalStateException: File has been moved - cannot be read again in Mulipart file upload Spring MVC with JavaMail

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-mail

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: File has been moved - cannot be read again

I'm getting this exception and mail is not sending using javamail. It is working fine when only one attachment is there only,its not working if more than one file is being uploaded.

```
public class SomeClass {

    @Override
    public void sendMail(EmailReportsVO report) throws Exception {
        taskExecutor.execute( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {

                    List<String> absolutePaths=new ArrayList<String>();
                    List<MultipartFile> file = report.getFile();
                    System.err.println("file size::"+report.getFile()+ " :: size is ::"+file.size());
                    if(file.size()>0){
                        for (MultipartFile mFile : file) {
                            if(mFile.getSize()>0){
                                Thread.sleep(mFile.getSize()+1000);
                                File fileData = convert(mFile);
                                String absolutePath = fileData.getAbsolutePath();
                                absolutePaths.add(absolutePath);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    sendMailSimple(report.getMessageBody(), report.getMailTo(), report.getSubject(), absolutePaths);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public File convert(MultipartFile multipart) throws IllegalStateException, IOException, InterruptedException {
        File convFile = new File( multipart.getOriginalFilename());
        multipart.transferTo(convFile);
        return convFile;
    }

    private void sendMailSimple(String text,  String to, String subject, List<String> filePaths) throws Exception {
        MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
        try {
            MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
            helper.setFrom("lottisrikanth@gmail.com");
            helper.setTo(to);
            helper.setSubject(subject);
            helper.setText(text);

            if(filePaths.size()>0){
                FileSystemResource file =null;
                for (String filePath : filePaths) {
                    System.err.println("Hello path:: "+filePath);
                    file =new FileSystemResource(filePath);
 helper.addAttachment(file.getFilename(), file);
                }


            }
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new MailParseException(e);
        }
        mailSender.send(message);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you want the `helper.addAttachment` call inside the `for` loop?

There may be some other errors with file names and when files are removed, but I can't tell from the information you've provided.

Comment: even if i keep helper.addAttachment in side for loop also iam getting the same issue.

Comment: Are you sure nothing is removing the file before you send the message?  Add some code to prove it.